# Add Loading Graphic To JQuery UI Ajax Tabs?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

How can I add a loading graphic to the JQuery UI ajax tabs? So it pauses for half a second, displays the graphic then loads the content?

Here's the code I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                $(anchor.hash).html("I tried to load this, but couldn't. Try one of the other links?");
            }


        }
    });
});
```

This is the type of graphic I want to use in case you aren't sure:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the UI examples@ http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-spinner

The HTML content of this string is shown in a tab title while remote content is loading. Pass in empty string to deactivate that behavior. An span element must be present in the A tag of the title, for the spinner content to be visible.

```
Get or set the spinner option, after init.

    //getter
    var spinner = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "spinner" );
    //setter
    $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "spinner", 'Retrieving data...' );
```

SO your code would be:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                $(anchor.hash).html("I tried to load this, but couldn't. Try one of the other links?");
            },
spinner: '<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi5r5.gif" />'


        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Not exactly - the spinner only goes for the tab label itself! Meaning the image will shown in the tab label and only if <span></span> is set in the <a> tag!

Comment: We managed to get this right and it shows when loading, but it doesn't hide after loading is complete even though we confirmed the ajax load to have completed successfully. Anyone know why this would be?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show exactly what code is working for you, and then comment here and I will update my answer, or comment accordingly. Better would be to ask a new question, then you would have the whole community at your disposal.