# How to initialize jQuery UI tabs?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery

I am looking at the following SO answer, and it says:

> Get or set the spinner option, after init.
>
> ```
> //getter 
> var spinner = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "spinner" ); 
> //setter 
> $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "spinner", 'Retrieving data...' );
> ```

Where is init?  How do I set the getter and setter?  Thanks for your help!

[Add Loading Graphic To JQuery UI Ajax Tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944482/add-loading-graphic-to-jquery-ui-ajax-tabs)

Here is my script:

```
 $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            ajaxOptions: {
                error: function (xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                    $(anchor.hash).html("I tried to load this, but couldn't. Try one of the other links?");
                },
                spinner: '<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi5r5.gif" />'
            }
        });
    });
```

My HTML/Razor code:

```
<div id="tabs">

    <ul>
       <li><a href="#tabs-1"><span>News-1</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="@Url.Action("GetNews", "Home")"><span>Headline News</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>News-2</legend>
            <p>My News.</p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please re-write your question so that it's fully self-contained and does not rely on other questions/answers to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the documentation under the **Options** tab: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-spinner