# Ajax loader in jquery Tabs

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, tabs

I am having a Jquery UI tabs in my page.

I like to show a loader similar to ajax loader while changing the tabs. I refered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3944482/1716774). But till now i dont have any clear idea for how to make this.

I have tried this in my script like this.

```
 <script>
$(function() {
$("#tabs").tabs({

    ajaxOptions: {

        error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
            $(anchor.hash).html("I tried to load this, but couldn't. Try one of the other links?");
             var spinner = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "spinner" );
             $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "spinner", 'Retrieving data...' );
        },
 spinner: '<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi5r5.gif" />'


    }
});
});
</script>
```

How to make this in easy way. (I prefer not to use ajax method here.)

Like this image
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I also was looking for a simpler way without ajax setup and stumbled on this post. Frans answer was almost correct but updating the wrong element. The corrected version should look like this, he was updating the actual tab and not the panel.

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
  beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
      ui.panel.html('<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi5r5.gif" />');
  }
});
```

I just implemented works well.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
   beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
      ui.tab.html('<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi5r5.gif" />');
   }
});
```

Just rewrite html content of your tab with your desire loading gif. When the Ajax call is complete, tab content will be rewritten automatically.

More information: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeLoad